# How to solve the problem of getting req.cookies being undefined in production environment?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, jwt, render

```js
//back end sign in controller
const signinController= async (req,res)=>
{
    const{email,password}=req.body

    try {
        const user= await User.findOne({email:email})
        if(!user)
        {
            res.status(400).json({errorMessage:"This email is not registered, please signup"})
        }
        else
        {
            let status= await bcrypt.compare(password,user.password)
            if(!status)
            {
                res.status(400).json({errorMessage:"Incorrect password"})
            }
            else
            {
                const payload={
                    user:{
                        _id:user._id
                    }
                }
                jwt.sign(payload,jwtSecret,{expiresIn:jwtExpire},(err,token)=>
                {
                    const{_id,username,email,role}=user
                    if(err)
                    {
                        console.log("jwterror :  ",err)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       
                        res.status(200).json({token,user:{_id,username,email,role}})
                    }
                })
                
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        
        if(error)
        {
            console.log(error)
            res.status(400).json({errorMessage:"server error"})
        }
    }
}
// front end part
const handleSubmit=(e)=>
{
  e.preventDefault()

  if(isEmpty(email.trim())||isEmpty(password.trim()))
  {
    setFormData({...formData,errorMsg:"Fields are empty"})
  }
  else if(!isEmail(email))
  {
    setFormData({...formData,errorMsg:"Invalid email"})
  }
  else
  {
    setFormData({...formData,loading:true})
      signinAuth({email,password}).then((res)=>
      {
        
        setFormData({...formData,loading:false,errorMsg:false})
        setAuthentication(res.data.token,res.data.user)
        
        if(isAuthenticated() && isAuthenticated().role===1)
        {
         
          
          history.push("/admin/dashboard")
        }
        else
        {
          
          
          history.push("/user/dashboard")
        }
         

      }).catch((err)=>
      {
        
        setFormData({...formData,loading:false,errorMsg:err.response.data.errorMessage})
      })
  }
}



export const signinAuth= async(data)=>
{
   const config={
      headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"}
   }
   let response= await axios.post(`${api}/api/auth/signin`,data,config)
   return response
}

export const setAuthentication=(token,user)=>
{
    setCookies("token",token)
    setLocalStorage("user",user)
}
export const setCookies=(key,value)=>
{
    cookies.set(key,value,{expires:1})
}
```

I am unable to get req.cookies to verify JWT in production environment, but locally the code is working and I am able to get the req.cookies.

```js
//jwt verification middleware

const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const {jwtSecret}= require("../Config/Keys")

exports.jwtAuthenticator=(req,res,next)=>
{
   const token = req.cookies.token
   
   if(!token)
   {
    res.status(400).json({"errorMessage" :"authorisation denied because no token"})
   }
   try {
    const decoded=jwt.verify(token,jwtSecret)
    req.user=decoded.user
    next()
   } catch (error) {
    console.log("jwt error: ",error)
    res.status(401).json({"errorMessage" :"authorisation denied"})
   }
   
// app.js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose=require("./database/db")
const cors= require("cors")
const authRouter= require("./Routes/Auth")
const categoryRoute= require("./Routes/Category")
const productRoute= require("./Routes/Product")
const cartRoute= require("./Routes/Cart")
const orderRoute=require("./Routes/Order")
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const dotenv= require("dotenv")
dotenv.config();


const app= express();

const PORT=process.env.PORT||5000
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const corsOptions ={
    origin:'http://localhost:3000', 
    credentials:true          //access-control-allow-credentials:true
    
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
app.use(morgan("dev"))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use("/api/auth",authRouter)
app.use("/api/category",categoryRoute)
app.use("/api/product",productRoute)
app.use("/api/cart",cartRoute)
app.use("/api/order",orderRoute)


mongoose.connectDB()


app.get("/",(req,res)=>
{
    res.send("server")
})






app.listen(PORT,()=>
{
    console.log(`server connected to ${PORT}`)
})
```

I am unable to get req.cookies to verify JWT in production environment(render platform). However, I am able to fetch cookies locally.

I have tried these [JWT middleware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfxIH.png),
[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al5sY.png) code locally and it is working. However, after deploying, I couldn't able to get req.cookies.

Comment: Can you please format your code in the post and not just an image of code, it will be more easier for us to help.

Comment: Thank you for your attention.  I have added the code snippets..

Comment: ok, can you show the part where you login the first time, and when you set up the cookie on the header ?

Comment: I have updated.. please look into it

Comment: looks like you want to check the token set in the cookie, however you're setting up the cookie with token on the frontend, and this can be a issue since by default on production httpOnly is set to true for security and good practice, therefore you cannot manipulate the cookie on the frontend, usually we can set the cookie on the backend, or how about attaching on the request header the "Bearer token" to send the request instead from the cookie on the front ?

Comment: actually on login I am able to store token in cookies in both development and production . The problem is I couldn't able to parse the cookie when I need the token for authorization . so that req.cookies is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update2**: give a try with this setting on the cookie if you want to set the cookie on the frontend, (i am not familiar though on the front)

```
export const setAuthentication=(token,user)=> {
    setCookies(token)
    setLocalStorage("user",user)
}

export const setCookies=(value)=> {
    cookies.set("token", value, {
       sameSite: "none" //none for cross domain cookie, If omitted, it's set to 'no_restriction'.
       secure: true, //required for sameSite=none attribute, set to false by default in local dev
       expires: 1,
    })
 }
```

Maybe have a look on the cookies.set() documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/set
By default httpOnly is indeed false, that's why you can set cookie on the frontend.

**2nd Solution:** in case you just can't make it work, another common approch would be storing the jwt token in the localstorage just like how you do with the user, and retrieve it when you need by attaching it on your header, but again in my opinion setting this in localstorage or even manipulating cookie on the front is not the best practice, i believe setting all this stuff on the backend with httpOnly and secure cookie flags, or storing jwt in memory for direct use (some limitation) is still the best way to go.

```
export const setAuthentication=(token,user)=> {
    setLocalStorage("token", token) // you have to make a function to store the token like how you do on the user.
    setLocalStorage("user",user)
}

    // addtoCard endpoint
    const addToCart=async (productId)=> {
        
        let user= localStorage.getItem("user")
        user= JSON.parse(user)
        let userId=user._id
        let data={
          userId,
          productId
        }
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    
        const config={
            headers:{
                "Content-Type":"application/json",
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            },
          "withCredentials": true
        }
        await axios.post(`${api}/api/cart/addtocart`,data,config).then((res)=> {
          console.log(res.data.message)
        })
    }
```

than you just need to change the condition checking on the header instead of cookie and change the process in the middleware jwtAuthenticator:

```
exports.jwtAuthenticator=(req,res,next)=> {
   const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
   console.log(authHeader)
   if(!authHeader) {
        return res.status(400).json({"errorMessage" :"authorisation denied because no token"})
   }
   try {
        const token = authHeader.split('')[1];
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret)
        if(decoded) {
           req.user = decoded.user
           next(); 
        }
   } catch (error) {
        console.log("jwt error: ",error)
        res.status(403).json({"errorMessage": "forbidden token"})
   }
};
```

Comment: the problem remains the same.

Comment: so req.cookies.token is undefined after deployment in the jwtAuthenticator middleware?  and you get the expected error message "authorisation denied because no token" ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly..                       .

Comment: I can't figure it out as what i can see, will need to dive in more, can you update the question and show your endpoint where you use the middleware jwtAuthenticator ?

Comment: I updated it as an answer. please look into it

Comment: Can you check on your Network tab when you make the request on the endpoint "/addtocart" on deployment if you have the cookie property set correctly on the request header ? if it's not there that mean the cookie is not set for some reason, i update the answer to see.

Comment: cookie is present while making the addtocart request. I have included the options that you mentioned in cookies.set still I am not able to get the req.cookies. Is there chance that the problem might be of cors?

Comment: I change a bit on the setting and update my answer so test just in case, so the cookie is present and your token value is set as expected on the request header even after deployment ? I don't really get it, you have a different domain on the backend I supposed since you use cors, but you have already enable the credential options, and it didn't seen like you got any error...

Answer (score 0):

```js
//in signin i didn't need to use the jwt middleware. during signin I am only setting the generated token in cookie. I am using JWT middleware for verification is in route that used to add products to cart. and codes are mentioned below

//signin route
const express= require("express")
const {signupValidator,validatorResult}= require("../Middlewares/Validator")
const {signupController,signinController} =require("../Controllers/Auth")

 const router= express.Router()



router.post("/signup",signupValidator,validatorResult,signupController)

router.post("/signin",signinController)

module.exports=router

//add to cart route
const express= require("express");
const { jwtAuthenticator } = require("../Middlewares/Authenticator");
const {AddToCart,GetCart,IncQuantity,DecQuantity,RemoveProduct,GetExactCart,RemoveCart} = require("../Controllers/Cart")
const router= express.Router()
router.post("/addtocart",jwtAuthenticator,AddToCart)
router.get("/getcart/:userId",GetCart)
router.get("/getexactcart/:userId",GetExactCart)
router.patch("/incquantity",jwtAuthenticator,IncQuantity)
router.patch("/decquantity",jwtAuthenticator,DecQuantity)
router.patch("/removeProduct",jwtAuthenticator,RemoveProduct)
router.patch("/removeCart/:userId",RemoveCart)

module.exports= router;
```

```js
//front end part of calling this addtocart api

const addToCart=async (productId)=>
  {
    
    let user= localStorage.getItem("user")
    user= JSON.parse(user)
    let userId=user._id
    let data={
      userId,
      productId
    }
    const config={
      headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"},
      "withCredentials":true
     }
    await axios.post(`${api}/api/cart/addtocart`,data,config).then((res)=>
    {
      console.log(res.data.message)
    })
    
  }
```